# A few questions about writing my own account registration methods in .Net Mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to write my own account registration logic in an Mvc 4 application. I started with a basic template instead of the internet template. At the moment I have a `Tenant` model with a number of properties. Using code first I've created a tenant table in my database (there will be more models and tables added over time - I'm just trying to get one working first).

I've created a **RegisterTenantModel** - similar to the one in the internet template except I'm using email instead of username.

```
public class TenantRegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

In my **RegisterTenant** method below I want to:

- Allow a user (tenant) to initially sign up only with an email address and password, and only allow them to enter the rest of their tenant related properties once their account has been verified by email, hence the use of the `TenantRegisterModel`.

On calling `Membership.CreateUser`, how do I know that `model.Email` and `model.Password` will be added to the `Tenant` table? Likewise, if I was doing the same scenario as described above for a `Landlord`, how would I know that the details entered are being added to the `Landlord` table? Is there a way with `Membership.CreateUser` I can specify what table to add the user's details too?

**RegisterTenant:**

```
public ActionResult RegisterTenant(TenantRegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register a tenant account
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            Membership.CreateUser(model.Email, model.Password);
            // ...
        }
    }
```

I of course have a context class, which at the moment has `public DbSet<LetLord.Models.Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }`, so how do I know what table a user's details are being added if I had multiple DbSets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How do I know that model.Email and model.Password will be added to the Tenant table?**

I added additional properties to the UserProfile model. Then in the `CreateUserAndAccount` method I dynamically passed the properties in as follows:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, 
                                            new { Email = model.Email,
                                                  FirstName = model.FirstName,
                                                  LastName = model.LastName,
                                                  AccountType = model.AccountType,
                                                  DaytimeContactNumber = "",
                                                  EveningContactNumber = "" },
                                            false);
```

**Likewise, if I was doing the same scenario as described above for a Landlord, how would I know that the details entered are being added to the Landlord table? Is there a way with Membership.CreateUser I can specify what table to add the user's details too?**

I created roles for landlords and tenants, and in `Register`, just after `CreateUserAndAccount` I checked the value of enum `AccountType`:

```
if (model.AccountType == AccountType.Tenant)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "Tenant");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("Unable to add user to role", e);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

MVC 4 Does not use the same membership as MVC 3. You want to look up simplemembership.  This is actually a very good solution to the common issue of storing additional data for a user.

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

this is a good place to start reading about it. Not sure how familiar you are with the MVC3 Membership Provider and Database Schema but this has changed a lot in MVC4. It took me a while to find everything.

Basically with the new setup you can create your own user table with any info you want and simply map 1 column of your database for the id (which is now an int and not a (guid) like the mvc3 membership provider and schema) and the "username" which can be an email or any unique identifier like that

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: false);
```

You link up your connection string to the database and it will create the membership schema with that database. Then you can add the model to your context and use Entity framework for functions like dbcontext.UserProfile.FirstName and such.

here is some more starting point material

http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/asp-net-membership-with-mvc4

good luck

Answer (score 1):

You should probably implement `Membership` by yourself and register it as `MembershipProvider` in your web.config. This way you have full control what happens with the data and you still have all the nice features.

There is a [sample project](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3f98d8eb-75b8-4913-963a-8d37f4326e88) in MVC3 that implements a Code-first Membership- and Roleprovider which would give you an idea about how it's done.

Alternatively, you could use the ProfileProvider to save some activation key (and your other custom user fields) and add the user to some role like `"NotActivated"`.

Update: to my knowledge, the standard Membership-Provider uses the DefaultConnection in the web.config. If you use Code-First in the same database, it will break because there's a structure that is not made from code-first already. You could use database-first alternatively, I think.

Comment: I'm looking into the sample you gave, and will report back.